# How to store Patterns in specific matrix index in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, matrix, arraylist, data-mining

I have a piece of pseudo code that I can't convert it to Java code properly, My first problem is the data structure that I use. I have to use a data structure that can handle large data sets and must be scalable. I'll show this part of the pseudo code and ask the questions:

```
 Create a matrix of pattern lists ptList |A] x |A|
 For i = |sk| - maxError to |sk| -1 
 For j = i +1 to |sk|
 Construct new pattern p = {sk [i], sk [j]}

 If p NOT in ptList [sk [j], sk [j]] then     
     then Add p to ptList [sk [j], sk [j]]
 Add (k,i,j) to ptList [sk [j], sk [j]].getLocationList (p)
```

So first I have to create a matrix and search for patterns, then after finding the patterns I have to add the patterns into [j][j] position, for example pattern (3,28) must be added to the the location [28][28] and so on .but when I do that java gives me IndexOutOfBoundException  and then I have to store a triple in the same location. Is that possible?I used ArrayList and List, but I couldn't do the job.
last question, can anyone explain what is the meaning of the last line of the pseudo code? how can I generate a location list for the same pattern and in the same location.

Comment: how big is the "large dataset" you're talking about?

Comment: Needs more background here.  What is this algorithm trying to do?  What is "ptList"?  What is "maxError"?  What is "getLocationList"?   This needs a lot more context.   Part of the answer to the size/memory issue depends on whether this matrix is very sparse, or very dense.  I'm not sure I can even tell from the pseudo code because I don't know what those other things are.

Comment: @Leo The datasets might contain 50,000 sequences and each sequence contains average 35 Items that means more than 2 million Items.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits The algorithm called IPM, it used to mine frequent sequences from web traces . ptList is the matrix that I have to create Now the most important thing is can I store a pattern at [j][j] position before I add all the patterns? as for the other parts it might take one day to explain.

Comment: Yes you can store a pattern at [j][j]. But did you make sure sk[j] is in bounds? I mean if the Matrix is AxA is sk[j]<A? And even more: Is sk-maxError >= 0 ? Is sk-1 >= 0 ? ...

Comment: Can you post the java code and stacktrace?

Comment: @Hk148 you've got several people here trying to help you, but lacking the information to do so.  Please don't follow up in comments here, edit your question and add the context that people are requesting, and people can help.  You might consider providing an example of what a "web trace" is, or a link to more information on the algorithm.  Other data you've provided (50,000 sequences) should be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what data type you need to store, assuming your patterns have class `Something`.

```
int sizeofA = -1; // Insert size of |A|
List<List<Something>> matrix = new ArrayList<>(sizeofA);
for(int i = 0; i < sizeofA; ++i)
    matrix.add(new ArrayList<Something>(sizeofA));

// Insert at position i, j
matrix.get(i).get(j).add(value);
```

It's not always the most efficient one, but it's not too bad either, and straightforward.